# Units in Polynomial Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Give an example of a natural number $n > 1$ and a polynomial $f(x) ∈ \Bbb Z_n[x]$ of degree $> 0$ that is a unit in $\Bbb Z_n[x]$.

I am trying to understand how units work in polynomial rings. My book doesn't really define it and I need a bit of help with this.

Comment: They are the same units as $\Bbb Z_n$

Comment: Not quite: the O.P. works in $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Right, I meant to say that, but more generally if $R$ is a integral domain, then the units of $R[x]$ are the units in $R.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note that $(2x+1)(2x+1)=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

For another example, use $\mathbb{Z}_9$. Note that $(3x+1)(6x+1)=1$, so $3x+1$ has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: So then $2(2x^2 + 2x +1)$ where $2$ is the natural number and $(2x^2 + 2x +1)$ is the polynomial?

Comment: @Nid, no he meant $(2x + 1)(2x + 1) = 4x^2 + 4x + 1 = 0x^2 + 0x + 1$

Comment: Oh ok. I multiplied that out wrong. So given what he just said. How would I use that hint to solve the above? @Nameless

Comment: $2x+1$ is a unit, since it has an inverse, in this case itself.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial is a unit if its constant term is a unit, and the coefficients of its higher degree terms are nilpotent.